# How to modifiy line to line auto scrolling behaviour in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

When executing a script line by line in RStudio, the next chunks of code will appear automatically (the auto scrolling gets activated) when you're executing the fourth last visible line. This behavior is fine when having four panes, because it keeps the executed line on the middle of the screen.

I chose to reduce the left down  pane to make room for the script. Now I would like to change the auto scrolling behavior, so that the next lines wont show at the bottom of the script (line 27 in picture) but on the middle of the screen(around line 14).

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under options/global options/code/display, there is an option **Allow scroll past end of document** and **highlight selected line**

I am not sure whether this will help you, but to my understanding, Rstudio could not auto-scroll the page and make the line executed displayed at the center.